How I can make AndroidX86 Access the physical Wi-fi card that I passthrough the VM?
In my VM I loaded Android X86 and I gave access to the wi-fi card:

But for some reason I see no way to have access towards it nor having wifi enabled. Is there a way for my AndroidX86 to manage directly the wifi card?

Android bases on Linux and Wifi drivers are often a pain on Linux as you have to compile them yourself (kernel module) or even patch the kernel. You have to check which Wifi drivers the Android x86 kernel provides and only those should be directly usable.

@Robert This is an half-truth. That said, it's indeed applicable here because many Realtek devices do not have driver in the older kernels Android typically uses.

As an alternate approach, could I passthrough the USB device to real Android Emulator with modern Android? Furthermore could I use an Atheros USB wifi device? If yes which one is the most appropriate for my goal?

It won't make a difference. It's either supported by the kernel or it isn't. The latter seems to be the situation here.

If my usb device was an Atheros one would it work? Or no USB wi-fi at any chipset is supported upon Android X86?

If my usb device was an Atheros one would it work? Very likely yes.
